# Display JLabels on a JPanel with fixed width in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I want to display a JFrame with two JPanels. For simplicity I have implemented a "placeholder" JPanel on the right half of the JFrame.
I want to achieve that on the left side of the JFrame a JPanel is shown, which is

a) Non resizeable in horizontal direction (it should have fixed width).

b) The class of the left JPanel should have a method to place JLabels as far up as possible on the JPanel (first JLabel as far up as possible, second JLabel under the first JLabel, third one under the second and so on), preferably in the center of the left JPanel.

My code is:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {

     public Test() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200,200);
    }

    public void addEntry() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        label.setText("Label test");
        this.add(label, gbc);
        this.validate();
    }
}
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,1));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Test test = new Test();

    JPanel placeholder = new JPanel();
    placeholder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    placeholder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    frame.add(test, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    frame.add(placeholder, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    test.addEntry();
    test.addEntry();
}
```

The status:

At the moment the left JPanel has fixed width as supposed to, but the JLabels are being added in vertical direction on the JPanel and are also not placed in center of the JPanel.

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wCED.jpg

[image]

EDIT:
Using mKorbel's advice to try a BoxLayout:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
public Test() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200,200);
}

public void addEntry() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("Label test");
    label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    this.add(label);
    this.revalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addEntry() method uses the same constraints so you won't get the results you want.

You need to create an instance variable, lets say "row" which is initially set to a value of 0. Then you add the component to the panel with an x value of 0 and a y value of "row". At the end of the method you increment row by 1 so that next time you invoke the method the y value will be 1, which will give you your vertical layout.

Or another option is to use a vertical BoxLayout. Then you don't need to worry about grid positions. Every time you add a component it will be added vertically. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I've edited my post with a version of a BoxLayout as you suggested. Works great for now. Can you tell me how to implement a vertical ScrollBar for scrolling through JLabels of the .addEntry() method? I've tried to simply add a JScrollBar, but cannot get the ScrollBar to be placed on the right end of the JPanel. This might be caused by the BoxLayout?

Comment: `I've tried to simply add a JScrollBar,` - you don't use a JScrollBar. You create a JScrollPane with the panel as the parameter. Then you add the scroll pane to the frame. The scrollbars will appear when required.

Comment: Just accepted your answer. Also I just tried it as you just suggested. The Scrollbar is not shown  (I did create a ScrollPane and added it to the frame). Do you see any reason?

Comment: You didn't post your code so I can't see what you are doing. However, there is no reason for the scrollbar to show up with only two labels added to the panel. The scrollbar will automatically appear as you add more labels to the panel and the label is outside the view of the scrollpane. If you want the scrollbar to always be visible then you need to read the JScrollPane API. You can set a parameter to always make the scrollbar visible even if it is not active.